# Where can I get two to four years worth of historic data news for companies included in DJ and S&P?

Tags: historical-data, news, data-source

Where can I get two to four years worth of historic data news for companies included in DJ and S&P? I mean not just prices historic data but also news.
Preferably for free and in CSV or any similar form.

Comment: Is this useful for you?

Answer (score 2):

### It seems that the way to do it free is to scrape them yourself.

**PAID Sources**

---

AP
http://www.ap.org/products-services/financial-services

---

Elektron Market Data Feeds | Thomson Reuters
http://financial.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/infrastructure/trading-infrastructure/elektron-enterprise-data-management/market-data-feeds.html

AlphaFlash | The fastest machine-readable economic news | AlphaFlash®
http://www.alphaflash.com/product-info/alphaflash-en

---

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Making an HTTP request using the following link will give you the end of day stock market data (in csv) for essential any security listed on an American exchange.

The URL parameter q specifies the ticker of the company you want to get data for. Also the date range is specified in the startdate and enddate parameters.

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=MSFT&startdate=Jan+1%2c+2010&enddate=May+17%2c+2016&output=csv

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Intrinio's api](http://docs.intrinio.com/#company-news). It isn't free but it's the cheapest I've come across for a retail investor (and I was actually suggested them by Xignite employee who suggested that they might be a good fit).

I write a C# wrapper for their API, but am not associated.. unfortunately I didnt need, and so didnt implement, the functionality to get the news data, but if you want to contribute at all, please feel free to do so, see [my intrinio wrapper source and feel free to make contributions](https://github.com/daleholborow/iayos.intrinioapi)